# How to prevent multiple Initialization of property from derived classes

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

**The code below is a short "summary" of my real project that contain only the relevant parts to understand my question. (and don`t want to ruin someones day with the original code).**

imagine you have 4 classes: Division, Branch, Department and Team. every class inherits base class in that order.

**The final goal:** return **one** division object that holds List of 7 Branches, each Branch holds List of 7 Departments and each Department holds List of 7 Teams.
for example i will be able to reach from outside to every class instance:

```
division d = new division();
d.CreateDivisionStructure();
int Example = d.ListOfBranches[5].ListOfDepartments[4].ListOfTeam[3].SomeIntegerProperty;
```

*(the original code has that lists, override functions, properties etc..)*

**the problem:** imagine that  `protected string _myVar` in the code below is a `Datatable` that needs to initialized via `myVar`property with heavy resource consuming SQL query. hence, my wish is to initialize `protected string _myVar` only one time for all the creation of the "division units structure". in the code below `protected string _myVar` will be null 64 times and will be initialized 64 times (for my understanding 7 times for each unit and one time for each `base()` call).

how can i achieve that?

i tried quite a lot other ways but could not solve that. I would appreciate any help, different way of thinking or advice.

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            division d = new division();
            d.CreateDivisionStructure();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


    class division

    {
        private static int CountHowManyTimesMyVarWasInitilized = 0;
        public division()

        {

        }

        protected string _myVar;

        public string myVar
        {
            get
            {
                if (_myVar == null)
                {
                    CountHowManyTimesMyVarWasInitilized++;
                    Console.WriteLine(CountHowManyTimesMyVarWasInitilized);
                    _myVar = "now myVar is not null";
                    return _myVar;
                }
                else
                { return _myVar; }

            }
            set { _myVar = value; }
        }

        public void CreateDivisionStructure()

        {

            Console.WriteLine(myVar);
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                Branch b = new Branch(7);
            }
        }
    }   

    class Branch : division

    {

        public Branch(bool dImDerivedClass)
        {
            //  constructor for department to prevent recursive stackoverflow if base of department will call the empty constructor
        }

        public Branch(int NumberOfBranches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myVar);
            Department d = new Department(7);
        }

    }


    class Department : Branch

    {


        public Department(bool ImDerivedClass) : base(true)
        {
            //  constructor for team to prevent recursive stackoverflow if base of Team will call the empty constructor
        }

        public Department(int numberOfDep) : base(true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDep; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myVar);
                Team t = new Team(7);
            }
        }
    }


    class Team : Department

    {
        public Team(int numberOfTeams) : base(true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTeams; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myVar);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you might be misusing inheritance. A Branch is not a Division and a Department is not a Branch etc. so should they really be inheriting from each other?

Comment: yes. for example revenue goals of team is derived from revenue goals of department and there are functions that handles it and calling Base() for the revenue goals of the class above in the hierarchy in order to calculate their revenue goals (its a business dashboard software).

Comment: As indicated in a comment, this is a poor design. If some code could be shared, then move it to another class... Even thou it might seems that you have less code to write, at some point in the future, it will make maintenance harder when you will realize that you don't want such high coupling...

Comment: you are right, i know the design must be improved i am sincerely thankful for all reviews on the design. but please explain to me why department should not inheritance Branch?

Comment: Because a department is not a branch. Inheritance would be more like "Department -> HR Department" where HR Department IS a Department itself but a specific kind. You are inheriting objects that are not in any way instances of their parent. Should you be able to call `Department.ScheduleBranchMeeting()`?

Comment: @Michael Weinand made it clear at the conversation with him below. would you adopt  his approach about the design? (he wrote his approach in comment not in the answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely a good use of the `Lazy<T>` class, used in a static variable so there is only a single copy for the process.  It will run the `Func` you give it once to initialize during the first access of the variable.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx

However, based on your class structure I'm not sure if it is the best approach.  What is the purpose for the hierarchy of `Branch : division` and `Department : Branch`.  Is the `Branch` a `Division`? If you are trying to share common properties as to not code them over again, I would suggest creating a common class that can hold those variables that `Branch`, `Division`, and `Department` can inherit from.

Comment: thank you for your answer. using Lazy<t> seems to be the most appropriate solution. the design at first was that all classes will inheritance Division but than i discovered that 1. there are a lot of shared properties 2.  calculations made by override functions are based on Base()  properties of each class in the hirarchy (see my comment to @leigero). if you would design it what was the design in the perspective of inheritance?

Comment: I would probably have a common base class, call it "BusinessUnit" that has all of your shared properties, then Division, Branch, Team, all inherit from BusinessUnit.  Make one of those properties the value you want to use for the calculations, make another property for "Parent" that references the hierarchical parent of that item, and another property for Children.  I would create a separate class that navigates the tree and does the calculations, one that can be unit tested for correctness.

Comment: i understand. we should have made this conversation 2 months ago (-:

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static variable / static constructor in the lowest class in the hierarchy. The static constructor will only be called once.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use a "control" variable.
I'm sure you can improve your design and avoid this problem but I don't have time to check it now..

```
using System;

namespace Program
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            division d = new division();
            d.CreateDivisionStructure();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    internal class division

    {
        private static int CountHowManyTimesMyVarWasInitilized = 0;

        public division()

        {
        }

        protected string _myVar;
        private bool _isReadyForInitialization;
        public string myVar
        {
            get
            {
                if (!_isReadyForInitialization)
                    return null;
                if (_myVar == null)
                {

                    CountHowManyTimesMyVarWasInitilized++;
                    Console.WriteLine(CountHowManyTimesMyVarWasInitilized);
                    _myVar = "now myVar is not null";
                    return _myVar;
                }
                else
                { return _myVar; }
            }
            set { _myVar = value; }
        }

        public void CreateDivisionStructure()

        {
            // now _myVar is spposed to be initilized to all dirved clasess isnt is?
            Console.WriteLine(myVar);
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                Branch b = new Branch(7);
            }
            _isReadyForInitialization = true;
            Console.WriteLine(myVar);
        }
    }

    internal class Branch : division

    {
        public Branch(bool dImDerivedClass)
        {
            //  constructor for department to prevent recursive stackoverflow if base of department will call the empty constructor
        }

        public Branch(int NumberOfBranches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myVar);
            Department d = new Department(7);
        }
    }

    internal class Department : Branch

    {
        public Department(bool ImDerivedClass) : base(true)
        {
            //  constructor for team to prevent recursive stackoverflow if base of Team will call the empty constructor
        }

        public Department(int numberOfDep) : base(true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDep; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myVar);
                Team t = new Team(7);
            }
        }
    }

    internal class Team : Department

    {
        public Team():base(false)
        {

        }
        public Team(int numberOfTeams) : base(true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTeams; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myVar);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. that seem to be not a bad idea but what are the benefits of that approach  comparred to @SledgeHammer sagastion - to use a static variable? (this comment is Directed to everybody).

Comment: @jonathana I think none of the above is ideal.
One advantage of my current solution over SledgeHammer 's is that for mine ,my "trick"  is just a private implementation detail.Noone knows about it

Comment: @jonathana is myVar the same for all divisions?
If not,I don't think the other solutions even apply to your case.
In any case,as others have said,you need to improve your design and not try to fix the current problem using "tricks"

Comment: yes, myVar is the same in all classes (identical data should be inside the datatable in all instances in real project)

Comment: @jonathana Then it should not be an "instance" property (and probably it shouldn't be on the Division class either).
Make it a static field(use Lazy<T> as Michael Weinand suggested) on a static class

Comment: i understand. tnx again.